# Выход с кодом 03, необработанные исключения?

Tags: c++, исключения

Выходит с кодом 03, я так понимаю это необработанное исключение, но не понимаю почему так происходит, псевдокод:

```
void Fun1(..)
{
   try
   {

      .... 

      do
      {
         Fun2(...);
         switch (GetLastError())
         {
             ....
             default:
               throw __LINE__; // вот тут все и заканчивается с кодом 03
         }

      } while ( y > 0 )

   }
   catch (int x)
   {
       cout << x;
   }
   catch (...)
   {
       cout << "?";
   }
}
```

Схема кода приведена дословно.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь генерировать макрос, а нужен обьект .  Попробуйте int ( 
   __LINE__ )

Comment: Вроде оно, спасибо. Есть ещё некоторые странности, понаблюдаю пока.. gcc что то очень не быстро начинает на нем стек разматывать.. с ощутимыми задержками